# How to insert vertical cut in delta symbol?

Tags: symbols

How to insert vertical cut in delta symbol to denote divided difference?

Comment: Could you show what result you want to achieve ?

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/159384/80509

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I have not found my answer as I wished. The shape I look for is like an "equilateral triangle together with a vertical median".

Answer (score 2):

This might be what you want. It can be adjusted if needs arise.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\divdiff}{\mathrel{\mathpalette\div@diff\relax}}
\newcommand{\div@diff}[2]{%
  \mathstrut\ooalign{\hidewidth$\m@th#1|$\hidewidth\cr$\m@th#1\bigtriangleup$\cr}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\divdiff B_{x\divdiff y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

An equilateral triangle with the bisector:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{pict2e}
\usepackage{color}
\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\divdiff}{\mathrel{\text{\div@diff}}}
\newcommand{\div@diff}{%
  \sbox\z@{$\m@th\bigtriangleup$}%
  \setlength{\unitlength}{\wd\z@}%
  \begin{picture}(1,0.69282)
  \linethickness{.09ex}
  \roundjoin
  \polyline(0.1,0)(0.9,0)(0.5,0.69282)(0.1,0)(0.5,0)
  \polyline(0.5,0.69282)(0.5,0)
  \end{picture}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

$A\divdiff B_{x\divdiff y}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, it is almost ok, but the median should not cross the base.

Comment: @KhirodBoruah Does the new one appeal more to you?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking by chance for something like this one:

```
234B     ⍋  Apl Functional Symbol Delta Stile
```

Since it is an APL character, you can try the package [APL](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/apl) from CTAN (it looks like a plain TeX package, but once you have the character, you can adapt it to use with LaTeX as well).

Alternatively, you can try to insert it directly from UNicode (given a UNicode font that supports this symbol).